# How do I write to a local file?

Tags: ruby, file

I'm learning Ruby, and can't figure out how to open and write to a local file. How can I open a file and write a string to it?

Comment: It would be really good if you spent time reading through [the core and standard Ruby libraries](http://www.ruby-doc.org/) to familiarize yourself with what's available. Even if you don't know what everything is used for, over time you'll run into the need, and, having glanced at the documentation a few times, you'll remember it's in there somewhere. As is, your question is very elementary, and very well explained by the [IO classes' documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html).

Answer (score 1):

Opening and writing to a file is done via Ruby's [File](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/File.html) class. Here's an example.

```
File.open('path/to/file.txt', 'w') do |file|
  file.write('this is how you write to a file')
end
```

The first argument to [`File#open`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/File.html#method-c-open) is the relative file location. The second is the [mode](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-c-new).

Comment: Don't forget to close the file, `file.close`, after you're done writing to it.

Comment: @HM1 the file will be automatically closed if a block is given.

Comment: Don't forget to close the question

Answer (score 0):

To read from `file`

```
File.read(file)
```

To write `string` to `file`

```
File.write(file, string)
```

Comment: @DavidLjungMadison, you probably should read the [IO class documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html) a bit more closely. @sawa's answer is correct as File inherits from IO, which has both class and instance versions of `read` and `write`.

Comment: @DavidLjungMadison Don't tell a lie. It was not added in Ruby 2.0. It is available at least in Ruby 1.9.3. Don't make an un-useful excuse.

Comment: @DavidLjungMadison Doesn't it even come to your mind to remove your first comment that is telling false information? Really surprising. All you think of is thinking what another layer of excuse to add?

Answer (score -1):

What exactly do you want? Do you want to download the photo and save it? Or do you want to save the URL of the photo?

You can save the photo with `Mechanize`, because `Mechanize.new.get` creates a new file retrieved from the given URL and response body.

```
file = Mechanize.new.get(url)
file.class #=> Is a file, returns Mechanize::File
file.save('photo.jpg')
```

You can name the file however you like, with the `#save` method.

Or you can save the URL of the photo in a file by using the Ruby [File](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/File.html) class.

```
File.open('photo_url.txt', 'w') { |file| file.write(url) }
```

The file will be automatically closed by Ruby after the block terminates.

Comment: There's nothing in the question hinting that the OP wants to retrieve an image from a URL.

Comment: There was, until it was edited

Answer (score -1):

one liner

```
File.open(path, "w") {|f| f.write(string)}
```

Comment: yeah you're right doing it this way is stupid